# Android-app: Old database still exists after switching to room database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

After switching to a room database I deleted the SQLite-Helper Class. But if I install my app the old database is still created on my smartphone.

I opened the the device file explorer and found under my project-folder 
/databases with the following databases

local.db which is my old database with date of 1970-01-19 and 2.5 MBytes
local_db which is the new room database
local_db-shm and local_db-wal whhich seem to be some room data

Even if I uninstall the app and reinstall it the local.db appears again. Deleting it does not help too.

But I think that I have deleted all the old SQLiteHelper Code. So does anyone know, where I might find the key to getting rid of the old database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the manifest (AndroidMainfest.xml) has `android:allowBackup="true"`, this could result in the data being restored automatically by the backup manager. From your description of the issue this could well be the cause.

Try changing to use `android:allowBackup="false"`, uninstalling the App and then re-installing.

Comment: Thank you very much - problem solved - and I never would have tried this

Comment: @E.Reuter that's good. Could you please tick the answer if you believe this helped you solve the problem.

Comment: I did, but it said that I have too few points for my vote  to be shown

Comment: @E.Reuter that's too few points to upvote (click the up arrow, I think you need 15 reputation to upvote and 200 to downvote). However, you can click the checkmark,without any reputaton,to say that the answer is the accepted answer that helped you solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry but this answer didn't help at all.. How do you handle that on a production app already installed by customers ?